# AutoHotKey Adding to End of a Number

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to set up AutoHotKey to do the following:
If I type "34c" I want it to change to "34°C" with any number.

17.5c → 17.5°C

It's easy to do with a "c" by itself by when it's at the end of a number I'm not sure how to make that work.

Comment: Do you want that conversion in a specific program or anywhere you type?

Comment: Anywhere I type would be ideal

Comment: `AutoHotKey` supports `RegExReplace` which can be used here. Syntax and example can be found [here](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm). However, i am not regex expert, so, cannot help further.

Comment: @andy Try this `:\d:c::°C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; *: An ending character is not required 
; ?: The hotstring will be triggered even when it is inside another word 

#Hotstring * ? 

::0c::0°C
::1c::1°C
; ...
::9c::9°C
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options

Answer (score 1):

The other answers above are more suited to your exact usage case, but this is my hotkey to convert "deg.", which makes it possible to type °F or °C anywhere in a sentence (regardless of whether it follows a numeric temperature or not).

```
:?*:deg.::°
```